# Moving Finger in blender Moves the other part of hand?

Tags: modeling, rigging

When I go into pose mode and move the index finger, it moves a part of the hand that isn't even connected to the index finger, I don't understand the issue and would appreciate some help, Thanks.

[Link To My Blender File...](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6tUWldJrYVHdV9xQ1cwRklhSjQ/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

The problem has to do with the vertex groups the bones influence.

When you parented your mesh to your armature blender created a vertex group on the child mesh for every bone in the armature.  Looking at the bone names you can see the bone with the problem is named "Bone_L.009".  You'll find the corresponding vertex group here:

[image]

Select the "Bone_L.009" vertex group and go into Weight Paint mode.

[image]

The problem is pretty obvious: the bone has influence on other parts of the mesh than the intended "finger" (you can see that there is a green area also on the other "finger", thus it is influenced by the same bone).

To correct, in the weight paint brush options set the Weight to 0 and then paint over the problem area of the mesh.

[image]

It should look something like this where you're done:

[image]

The fingers will now move independently.